# WordPress isn't working with email sender with reverse proxy amd https in docker

Tags: php, wordpress, email, nginx, proxy

I have started a wordpress docker and have my site built on that container.
The host machine is a standard EC2 of AWS.
In production we have an nginx reverse proxy that passing all the data of https to http, so the access to our site is by https.
I used to have a plugin form for contact section in my website for email purposes sign up, which is working in our dev machine but using reverse proxy https and docker isn't working.
We have installed a php plugin for sending emails, and i have exported the email ports from docker, and in addition i have verified that the wordpress container have the sendmail service

Note: sendnail 
  service is running inside the container but i can't send mail with this service
getting

> sendmail: Cannot open mail:25

Comment: Can you manually run sendmail in docker container and see if it works?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my container is running the sendmail service . I'll also add it to my question.

Comment: I mean run the command line sendmail command to check if email is received

Comment: Ok will do it shortly and update...

Comment: you were right, the sendmail isn't working from within the docker although i have everything needed installed...i have updated the issue with the error message i;m getting. any idea how can i set it up ..?

Comment: Post your docker-compose file

Comment: i'm just using the official latest wordpress docker file which can b found [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/666c5c06d7bc9d02c71fd48a74911248be6f5a5b/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157302/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user4860092).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either run a container with a smtp server and map that to your wordpress container or you need to map the HOST server smtp to your wordpress container

You can do that by running

```
docker run --extra_host "mail:<hostprivateip>" ... wordpress
```

Or you should use `docker-compose` for the same

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: wordpress
    ...
  mail:
    image: <somesmtpimage>
```

Comment: please ellaborate, docker don't know the --extra_host arument

Comment: Use `--add-host` instead. It is named `extra_hosts` in case of docker-compose